# React-Native re-render Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm having trouble keeping the data in my Flatlist after coming back from another page. My scenario is as follows:

1. User goes to homepage and scrolls through 20 items
2. User clicks their profile tab changing page using react-native-router-flux
3. User clicks the home tab taking them back to the list however the list re-renders and starts from the top.

How can I stop this re-rendering and fetching the same data again?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
}
```

makeRemoteReuest gets my data from firebase in batches of 5 and sets data: []

```
data: [...this.state.data, ...results]
```

I've tried using the below but not sure if this is correct, when i navigate away and back the data re-renders. I want to keep the data so the page will be exactly the same as when it was left.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.state.data) !== JSON.stringify(nextState.data)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My flatlist:

```
<View>
        <FlatList
          scrollsToTop={false}
          ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter()}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.newRefresh}
          onEndReached={this.handleEndRefresh}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
        {this.state.refreshAvailable ? this.renderRefreshButton() : null}
      </View>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use scrollToIndex method

Comment: thanks for the reply... the problem I have is that componentDidMount gets called when navigating back and it re-renders the Flatlist again. So if I was at index 20 > leave page > come back > re render only fetches first 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coded long back for the dumb project, maybe this can help you

**The View:**   used onLayout Prop for getting the y-axis

```
   <ScrollView
   ref={(ref) => this.scrollTo = ref}
   contentContainerStyle={{margin:5,}}
   >
   <Card onLayout={(event) => this._findHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout, 'personal')}>
    <Personal review={true}/>
   </Card>
   </ScrollView>
```

**The Function:** stored the y-axis; here i have used realm db

```
    _findHeight = (e, name) => {
      const {x, y, width, height} = e;
      this.realm.write(() => {
         this.realm.create('yLocation',{names:name,yaxis:y}) : 
      });
    }
```

**The AutoScroll Method**: here i have used scrollTo method from ScrollView you can use any method using their ref

```
_scrollTo = (y) => {
  this.scrollTo.scrollTo({x:0,y:y,animated:true});
}
```

**Note : Call _scrollTo method in componentDidMount**